# Game Center Integration

Tags: swift, integration, game-center

I'd like to integrate Game Center with my game, and I've already enabled it. I've found some code for authenticating the player (http://www.codeinjection.me/blog/2014/7/game-center-authentication-and-swift), but I don't know where to put it. And after authenticating the player, how should I go about implementing leaderboards and achievements? And displaying them in the game? Thanks in advance?

Edit: Also, the code in the link as well as many other authentication code samples I've seen for Swift use self.delegate? often, but when I try pasting the code into my program, it tells me that AppDelegate doesn't have a member named delegate. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Apple provides some great guides about Game Center, basically you will have to:

- Set up your leaderboards, achievements etc. in the iTunes Connect website: [Game Center Configuration Guide for iTunes Connect](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectGameCenter_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013726)
- Integrate the Game Center in your app: [Game Center Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

The player authentication is usually done in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` of the app delegate ([Apple sample code here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/GKAuthentication/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010933)). But the guides I mentioned explain everything, the code examples are in Objective-C but the APIs are the same in Swift, you just need to change the syntax for example:

```
GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];
```

Becomes

```
let localPlayer = GKLocalPlayer()
```

It's some homework to do, but that's the price if you want to use Swift ;)